# Blueprint 10 pixels vertical spacing

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I have the following divs.

```
<div class="container showgrid">

        <div class="span-24">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="span-24">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have the grid on and i can see that the space between the first div and the second is more than 10px.How can i have 10px space instead of the default,which looks like over 10px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default margin for Blueprint is `margin-right: 10px`. Have a look at their Grid Tests page here: http://blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/grid.html

Comment: What about the height of the vertical boxes,does bleuprint tell of their height,i have measured one of them,its 20px using measure it plugin on firefox but when i view the image on firefox,its 18px.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question! :)